# Appending string to list adds a '\r' to every element

Tags: python, string, file, append

I am trying to append a string to a list (seqs). The strings look something like random letters which I am reading line by line from a file. Printing out the string shows no sign of a '\r'. But printing out the list does.

```
   seqs.append(seq)
   print('seq is', seq)
```

gives: seq is CSMKMTIGSGTKTLHRWAFNPTQQTCVTFVYTGAAGNQNNFLTRNDCVNTC

```
   print(seqs)
```

gives: 'CSMKMTIGSGTKTLHRWAFNPTQQTCVTFVYTGAAGNQNNFLTRNDCVNTC\r'

I have tried changing the file a few different ways, even writing an example file of just lines of text so I am fairly certain I am not adding a '\r' to the file. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit**: I printed the sequence differently and I do see the carriage return now. Is there anyway I can remove it? For now when I parse through the sequences I just say if it's '\r' continue. To skip it

It's reading a gzip file and opening it with:

```
with gzip.open(filepath, 'rb') as fin: 
    file_content = fin.read().decode(encoding)
    lines = file_content.split('\n')
    for line in lines: #separate them into a list
```

**EDIT EDIT** I just did file_content.split('\r\n')...Seemed to fix the problem, not sure why I did not think of it sooner. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Try `print('seq is', seq, "xxx")`, and you'll see a sign of the carriage return.

Comment: How are you opening and reading this file? Because it looks like you have `\r\n` newlines (the default on Windows), and Python's universal newline handling isn't taking care of them for you for some reason. Fixing that is likely going to fix your sequence-related output issues.

Comment: You're printing `str(seq)` but `repr(seqs)`.

Comment: It's reading a gzip file and opening it with: gzip.open(filepath, 'rb') as fin:
        file_content = fin.read().decode(encoding) @Blckknght

Comment: Well, yes; if you open the file in a binary mode, then you will not get universal newline handling. `gzip.open` supports text modes - even though it must read the data as binary in order to get decompressible data - with a clever bit of wrapping. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) for details.

Comment: BTW: "I need to do it like this because I basically need every other line into two lists" A loop is not needed for this. Simply slice to create the desired lists: e.g. `evens, odds = lines[::2], lines[1::2]`.